# ExtJS handler in button

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a question about simple button.

**Below definition:**

```
var table = null;
var buttonConfig = {
    buttonId: 'mybutton1',
    text: 'Template button',
    icon: 'style/img/fam/button.png',
    tooltip: 'template button',
    handler: function () {
        var someConfig = null;
        fileProcessing(someButton, someConfig);
    }
};
addButtonToGrid(table, buttonConfig);
```

Function called `fileProcessing` has 2 args - `someButton` and `someConfig`.

I want to pass in `someButtton`, the button from object `buttonConfig`. How should I do it ?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like below:**

```
handler: function () {
    var someConfig = null;
    var someButton = this;
    fileProcessing(someButton, someConfig);
}
```

**[Reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-handler)**

> **PARAMETERS**
>
> button :  Ext.button.Button
>
> This button.
>
> e :  Ext.event.Event
>
> The click event.

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: This is it ! Thank you soo much. Soo we can close the topic